# Differentiable functions and sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f(x)$ be a differentiable function on $R$ with $\left|\,f'(x)\right|\leq r < 1$, here $r$ is a constant.  Consider the sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $x_1=0$, $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$, $n\geq 1.$ Show that $x_n \to x^*$ as $n\to\infty$. Moreover $x^*=f(x^*)$.  Such a point $x^*$ is called a fixed point of $f$.

Consider $x_{n+1}-x_n.$

Comment: Some of us don't like it when problems are dumped here, copied straight from an unidentified source, unaccompanied by any sign of effort by the person dumping the question. Please put some more effort into the presentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many answers to this question online: a quick Google will show you. However the reason *why* it is true is that if $|f'(x)|\leq r<1$ then $f(x)$ is a contraction.

Just consider a point $x_0$ and suppose $|f'(x_0)|\leq r<1$. Then there exists a point close to $x_0$ say $x_1$ such that

$$\left|\frac{f(x_1)-f(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}\right|<1\Rightarrow |f(x_1)-f(x_0)|<|x_1-x_0|,$$

That is, after applying the function, points that were close together get even closer together.

Now imagine $\mathbb{R}$ as a big ball, Venn diagram or even a line if you're not into the whole abstraction thing.

Keep applying the function until the space gets smaller and smaller and eventually contracts to a single point $x_\star$. Now this can't disappear because $f(x)$ is a function so essentially $f(x_\star)$ must equal $x_\star$... and it doesn't matter where you start because everything gets shrunk down to $x_\star$.

This is the *why*. A bit of Google will tell you how to make this idea rigorous.

Comment: McCarthy, could you please provide the google links, I am unable to come up with a formal proof

Comment: @om joglekar https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem